# Compiling multiple files in a single directory separately with CSC

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd, csc

I have multiple C# sources files (around 50) in a directory. What I want to do is to compile all of them separately, i.e. so that each of them should generate its own executable file. (Some of the files are one or 2 directories deep.)

Currently what i am doing is

```
csc *.cs /recurse:*.cs
```

The problem here is that CSC tries to compile all of the files together and finds multiple instance of the method `Main`. I know this is the correct behavior but this it's not what I'm looking for.

Is writing a batch script my only option or can I do some kind of single command wildcard magic to compile all of the files separately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a simple bat [for](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true) loop like

```
for /R %f in (*.cs) do csc %f
```

should do

Comment: Excellent That seems to be working, and although it is batch code ,it is a one liner.One of these days i will finally get myself to learn windows batch scripting. Cheers.

Comment: +1. CSC can only compile single DLL/EXE at a time. If you want to avoid batch script - consider MSBuild and creating corresponding project file. You should be able to make one that use *.cs and rule that executes csc on each to produce EXE.

Comment: The for loop is pretty handy to know, you can use it for batch conversions, some renaming and such things.