# How to import files in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a simple C# program. I have two files, `ClassA.cs` and `ClassB.cs`.

Each of these files implements its respective class.

I want to create an object of ClassB inside a method of ClassA.

My code looks like this:

ClassA.cs

```
using System;

public class ClassA {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {

        Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    }

    public ClassA() {

        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
    }
}
```

ClassB.cs

```
using System;

public class ClassB {

    public ClassB() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassB created.");
    }
}
```

How can I compile this project now? When I try to do `csc ClassA.cs ClassB.cs` I get the error `The type or namespace name 'ClassB' could not be found`.

I'm guessing I'm missing something like an `import` statement from Java or `include` from C++. What's the equivalent in C#?

Also, I'm not using an IDE. Only writing the files in a text editor and manually compiling / running in the console (windows).

Comment: I'd say, put them in the same namespace by putting a `namespace xxx { ... }` block around the class. Or, put them in _a_ namespace, at least, so you can import it.

Comment: what `csc` args are you using? These types aren't in namespaces (which is usually bad, but here... meh) - so you don't need any `using` directives - you just need both the files to go to the compiler.

Comment: @Nyerguds while that would be true in the general sense, that would actually make this *more complex* here; probably best to fix the immediate issue before adding that :)

Comment: @MarcGravell Well, I must admit I never tried building C# without IDE...

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm using the exact command I posted. ``csc ClassA.cs ClassB.cs``. Shouldn't this output a file called Class.exe?

Comment: @Tirafesi if no explicit name is specified, it takes the name from the first file, so: `ClassA.exe`

Comment: could this be as simple as not having saved the files?

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm sure I saved the files :b

Comment: @Tirafesi have you tried to use namespace?

Comment: Hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212833/compiling-multiple-files-in-a-single-directory-separately-with-csc?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212833/compiling-multiple-files-in-a-single-directory-separately-with-csc?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created 2 files in the same folder (`c:\code\egcsc`): `ClassA.cs` and `ClassB.cs`, with the respective contents you have shown.

Then:

```
c:\code\egcsc>dir
 Volume in drive C is (irrelevant)
 Volume Serial Number is (irrelevant)

 Directory of c:\code\egcsc

28/03/2018  12:26    <DIR>          .
28/03/2018  12:26    <DIR>          ..
28/03/2018  12:24               253 ClassA.cs
28/03/2018  12:25               126 ClassB.cs
               2 File(s)            379 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  (irrelevant) bytes free

c:\code\egcsc>csc ClassA.cs ClassB.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.8.0.62716 (e205ae18)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


c:\code\egcsc>ClassA.exe
Starting...
ClassB created.
```

So; it worked fine; you need to double-check what you have. Note: using a tool like VSCode or Visual Studio (there are free versions) would make this a lot easier...

Comment: I don't understand then... I run the exact same command and it doesn't work for me. Also, I'm using VSCode (which technically is an editor and not an ide)

Comment: Sigh... I fell like an idiot. There was a spelling mistake in the class name, which why it didn't compile... Sorry for wasting your time and thanks

Comment: @Tirafesi if you install the `ms-vscode.csharp` extension, it might be easier. This includes build tools, execution, debugging etc.